# Incorrect output in shellscript with ksh in Solaris

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh

I'm making a shell script using ksh as shell, the script takes a date as a parameter and searches for files named: camp_base_prueba_date.txt and rangos.txt and creates the arrays idcmps and ranks, the shell script is:

```
#!/bin/ksh    
set -A idcmps $(more /home/test/camp_base_prueba_$1.txt | awk '{print $1}')
set -A ranks $(more /home/test/rangos.txt | awk '{print $1}')
rm camp_plani_prueba_$1.txt

for idcmp in ${idcmps[@]}
do
   echo 'the id es: '$idcmp

    for rango in ${ranks[@]}
    do
      echo "the rank: "$rango
      liminf=$(echo $rango|cut -d'-' -f1)
      limsup=$(echo $rango|cut -d'-' -f2)
      echo 'limits: '$liminf'-'$limsup
      echo "****************************"
     done

done

exit
```

The file camp_base_prueba_$1.txt (where $1 is the current date) contains:

```
13416
38841
10383
10584
10445
10384
```

and the rangos.txt file contains:

```
0000-1999
2000-9999
10000-29999
```

when i run my shell as:

```
nohup ksh test.sh 14042014 > test.log 2>test.err
```

I obtain this stuff:

```
the id es: ::::::::::::::
the rank: ::::::::::::::
limits: ::::::::::::::-::::::::::::::
****************************
the rank: /home/test/rangos.txt
limits: /home/test/rangos.txt-/home/test/rangos.txt
****************************
the rank: ::::::::::::::
limits: ::::::::::::::-::::::::::::::
****************************
the rank: 0000-1999
limits: 0000-1999
****************************
....
```

The expected output should be:

```
the id es: 13416
the rank: 0000-1999
limits: 0000-1999
****************************
the rank: 2000-9999
limits: 2000-9999
****************************
the rank: 10000-29999
limits: 10000-29999
****************************
the id es: 38841
the rank: 0000-1999
limits: 0000-1999
****************************
the rank: 2000-9999
limits: 2000-9999
****************************
```

But apparently is creating the array with garbage, because the output shows the value of variables rank and idcmp  incorrectly (apparently garbage). What am I doing wrong? or what am I missing?, I have several days stuck with this stuff. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but under the motto "less code is better code", try changing your 2 array assignments to the form `set -A idcmps $(awk '{print $1}' /home/test/camp_base_prueba_$1.txt)` . Something about `more` may be screwing this up. If you really "need" to send data thru a pipe to awk (for some unstated reason), they you definitely want to use `cat file | awk ...`. Good luck.

Comment: What is `set - A`? I don't see it as one of the options - `set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [argument …]`

Comment: from man ksh93 `To assign values to an indexed array, use vname=(value . . .) or set -A vname value . . . . The value of all non-negative subscripts must be in the range of 0 through 4,194,303.`

Comment: @shellter Thanks. It wasn't present in the `bash set` options so got a little confused.

Comment: @ranvergara66 : You might want to also add what your expected output is from your sample data. Good luck.

Comment: @JS웃 : Yes, one of the several places that ksh and bash diverge. Good luck to all.

Comment: @JS웃 Sorry i forgot mention that i'm in a server Solaris

Comment: What is your script supposed to actually accomplish? I'm guessing your end goal could be achieved in about three lines if Awk (and a lot less tortured, too).

Comment: @JS웃 i edit the question adding the expected output,

Comment: FYI, you have a lot of bugs here around missing quoting. Always use `"$foo"`, not `$foo`, unless you *explicitly want* string-splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: ...also, using `more` is very much the wrong tool. To feed a file into awk's stdin, just run `awk ... <file`, not `more file | awk ...`

Comment: ...also, you can much more efficiently split the range with parameter expansion: `liminf=${rango%%-*}; limsup=${rango#-*}`; this doesn't have the performance overhead of a subshell running an external command.

Comment: Will it be too difficult to print the arrays before the loop? If it isn't too much to print them, maybe you should. Then you'll definitely know that `more` is causing it.

Comment: Which version?  Solaris 11 and later include ksh93 and use that for `/bin/ksh`, but Solaris 10 and older only have ksh88.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works when I test it locally:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -A idcmps $(awk '{print $1}' <"camp_base_prueba_$1.txt")
set -A ranks $(awk '{print $1}' <rangos.txt)
rm "camp_plani_prueba_$1.txt"

for idcmp in "${idcmps[@]}"; do
  echo "the id es: $idcmp"
  for rango in "${ranks[@]}"; do
    echo "the rank: "$rango
    liminf=${rango%%-*}
    limsup=${rango#*-}
    echo "limits: $liminf-$limsup"
    echo "****************************"
  done
done
```

...that said, it's still not very good code -- using string-splitting to populate the arrays, as done in the first two lines, is full of bugs.

Comment: great answer dude, but i dont understand the liminf=${rango%%-*} and limsup=${rango#*-} expressions.

Comment: @franvergara66, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 -- that's a bash reference, but these particular PEs are ones that made it into POSIX sh (and thus bash) by way of ksh.

Comment: I think the garbage in arrays is due to the "more" command because when i use the "cat" command, i dont have those problems

Comment: Thanks buddy, I'm pretty grateful to you.

Comment: @franvergara66, even `cat` is unnecessary inefficiency compared to just using `<file`.